# SQL Update If value = 1

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a SQL "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".  In that section of the update I have multiple fields.  One of the fields is active.  What I am trying to do is only update the active field if the current value is 1. I've know how to update if ISNULL: `active = ISNULL(@active, active)`.  Is there a way to do the same thing if the value is 1?

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                          display_name=VALUES(display_name),
                          wholesale=VALUES(wholesale),
                          saleWS=VALUES(saleWS),
                          taxable=VALUES(taxable),
                          sku=VALUES(sku),
                          code=VALUES(code),
                          onSale=VALUES(onSale),
                          description=VALUES(description),
                          link=VALUES(link),
                          image=VALUES(image),
                          display_page=VALUES(display_page),
                          attachment=VALUES(attachment),
                          applyCoupon=VALUES(applyCoupon)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how to update if `ISNULL`: `active = ISNULL(@active, active)`.
>
> Is there a way to do the same thing if the value is 1?

Yes, you can do that using a `CASE` expression:

```
active = CASE active WHEN 1 THEN @active ELSE active END
```

For the general case (say, if you wish to update `active` only when its current value is less than 123) you could use this syntax:

```
active = CASE WHEN active < 123 THEN @active ELSE active END
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this :

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(@active,1),active)
```

So when @active = 1 then it first make it null and then check for null.